# ¿Cómo crear una matriz, cada fila represente una imagen y cada columna número de píxeles? en R

Tags: r

Tengo las imágenes organizadas en subcarpetas, de la siguiente forma:

```
Carpeta -> imagenes_claseA -> img_01.jpg
                              img_02.jpg
                              ...
           imagenes_claseB -> img_01.jpg
                              img_02.jpg
                              ...
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es importar estas imágenes, y crear una matriz que cada fila represente una imagen y cada columna represente número de píxeles (son imágenes de distintos tamaños). Y además, agregar una nueva columna (clase) para indicar a cada imagen a que subcarpeta pertenece.

Lo de importar lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```
imagenes  = list.files(path="...",recursive=T,pattern=".jpg",full.names=T)
library(jpeg)
readImagen = function(f) {
   img = readJPEG(f)
}
```

Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, no es posible hacer lo que quieres realizar con una matriz, dado a que las observaciones de la matriz o son números o son cadena. El objeto ideal para almacenar estos datos es un `data.frame`.

Colocaré dos ejemplos. El primero es considerando el `nombre_archivo` + `.jpg`
 y la ruta absoluta del archivo. El segundo, considerando `nombre_archivo` y la ruta relativa o subcarpeta (se debe establecer el directorio de trabajo adecuado antes ejecutar la segunda opción).

```
# Primera opción
archivo <- list.files(path = "/Tu_ruta",pattern = ".jpg",recursive = T,full.names = T)

nombre <- gsub(pattern = ".*/",replacement = "",x = archivo)

df <- data.frame(NA,NA,NA)

for(i in 1:length(archivo)){
  df[i,1] <- nombre[i]
  df[i,2] <- prod(dim(jpeg::readJPEG(archivo[i]))[1:2])
  df[i,3] <- gsub(nombre[i],"",archivo[i]) 
}

names(df) <- c("Nombre","Pixeles","Ruta")


# Segunda opción
archivo <- list.files(path = "/Tu_ruta",pattern = ".jpg",recursive = T,full.names = F)

setwd("/Tu_ruta")

nombre <- gsub(pattern = ".*/",replacement = "",x = archivo)

df <- data.frame(NA,NA,NA)

for(i in 1:length(archivo)){
  df[i,1] <- gsub(".jpg","",nombre[i])
  df[i,2] <- prod(dim(jpeg::readJPEG(archivo[i]))[1:2])
  df[i,3] <- gsub(nombre[i],"",archivo[i],fixed = T)
}

names(df) <- c("Nombre","Pixeles","Subcarpeta")
```

Comment: Gracias @aldo_tapia